# laravel relation owner model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have Table like

```
TABLE USERS
  id
  username
  email
  password
  created_at
  updated_at
  created_by
  updated_by
```

i want to select `users` and join with this user to get the username by foreign key with created_by

Model Users

```
class users extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'users';

  public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongTo('App\Users','created_by');
  }
}
```

I want to know the user who created this user. I store users id on column created_by.

How to do this ?

Comment: Doesn't `users::with("user")->find(<id of user>)->user` give you what you need?

Comment: e.g i have 2 user A and B. But user B is created by A.I want to select user B to show this user B has created by A.name

Comment: `$A = users::with("user")->find(A)` and then `echo $A->name." was created by ".$A->user->name;` ? Isn't that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with()` function to get what you want, in your case you can have:

```
$users = user::with('user')->get();
```

For more information you can visit: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

### Model names must be capitalized and singular.

```
class User extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'users';

  public function creatorUser()
  {
     return $this->belongTo('App\Users','created_by');
  }
}
```

---

```
$creatorUser = User::findOrFail($someUserId)->creatorUser;
```